# Mathematica Module for Denavit-Hartenberg Parameters to Transformation Matrix

Tags: matrix, geometric-transform

I need to write a Mathematica module to get a 4*4 transformation matrix given the Denavit-Hartenberg parameters of the manipulator. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is direct implementation as given in:

Reference: [Denavit Hartenberg_parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit%E2%80%93Hartenberg_parameters)

```
dhTransformation[theta_, d_, r_, alpha_] := {
   {Cos[theta], -Sin[theta] Cos[alpha], Sin[theta] Sin[alpha], r Cos[theta]}, 
   {Sin[theta], Cos[theta] Cos[alpha], -Cos[theta] Sin[alpha], r Sin[theta]}, 
   {0, Sin[alpha], Cos[alpha], d}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thnaks for the answer